# Why does $\arctan(x)= \frac{1}{2i}\log \left( \frac{x-i}{x+i}\right)+k$?

Tags: integration

Letting $x=\tan(u)$,
$$\int\frac{1}{1+x^2} \, dx=\int\frac{1}{1+\tan(u)^2}\sec^2(u) \, du=u+k=\arctan(x)+k$$
Also, 
$$\int\frac{1}{1+x^2} \, dx=\int\frac{1}{(x-i)(x+i)} \, dx=\frac{1}{2i}\int\frac{1}{(x-i)}-\frac{1}{(x+i)} \, dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\ln(x-i)-\ln(x+i)\right)+c$$
$$=\frac{1}{2i}\ln \left(\frac{x-i}{x+i} \right)+c$$
Giving
$$\arctan(x)=\frac{1}{2i}\ln \left(\frac{x-i}{x+i} \right)+q$$

Why is this correct? What is the nature of $q$ (is it 'flexible' so the equality doesn't really mean much)?

I think it probably has something to do with the relationship between $\log(z)$ and $\arg(z)$, but $\arg(z\pm i)$ is hard to calculate neatly.

Comment: $e^{iz} = \cos z+i\sin z$.  I've posted a fairly short argument based on that.

Comment: It would be a nice exercise to plug in x = 1 on both sides of that equation. arctan(1) is ofcourse a well known value. Try to get that value from the right side too...

Comment: Are there typos in the u-substitution?

Comment: Don't think so, what would be incorrect?

Comment: Well. I'm seeing x replaced with tan(x), and not all the x's substituted out of the integrand.

Comment: @User58220 Yes, there were typos, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: NB: the constant q above is $\pi/2$. To connect with the formula from @MichaelHardy, use $\ln(-z) = \ln(e^{i\pi}z) = \ln(e^{i\pi})+\ln(z)=i\pi+\ln(z)$.

Answer (score 28):

The basic identity used here was discovered in the 18th century by Leonhard Euler:
$$
e^{iz} = \cos z+i\sin z
$$
where of course the cosine and the sine are of $x$ in *radians*.

It follows that $\cos z = \dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ and $\sin z = \dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$.

Therefore
$$
a= \tan z = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{i(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})} = -i\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{e^{2iz}+1} = -i\frac{b-1}{b+1}.
$$
$$
\begin{align}
a & = -i\frac{b-1}{b+1} \\[10pt]
(b+1)a & = -i(b-1) \\[10pt]
b(i+a) & = i-a \\[10pt]
b & = \frac{i-a}{i+a} \\[10pt]
e^{2iz} & = \frac{i-a}{i+a} \\[10pt]
2iz & = \log \frac{i-a}{i+a}
\end{align}
$$
The logarithm, like the arctangent, is "multiple-valued".

Comment: Thank you, it's nice to have things explicitly stated from the basics.

Answer (score 8):

We have that $$i\sin z=\sinh iz$$ $$\cos z=\cosh iz$$

This means that $$i\tan z=\tanh iz$$

But $$\tanh^{-1}z=\frac 1 2\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$$

Comment: Does that definition for $\tanh^{-1}(z)$ come from $\tanh(z)= \frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{e^z+e^{-z}}$? That's the problem I was having.

Comment: @Alyosha Yes. Actually, it is easier yo use $$\tanh z=\frac{e^{2z}-1}{e^{2z}+1}$$ to find the inverse.

Answer (score 6):

This is correct, and by letting $x$ tend to $+\infty$ you can find the constant term: $$\arctan(x) = \frac{1}{2i} \log(\frac{x-i}{x+i}) + \frac{\pi}{2},$$ since $\log(\frac{x-i}{x+i})$ tends to $\log(1) = 0$ and $\arctan(x)$ tends to $\pi / 2$.

This is valid for $x > 0$. Unfortunately, there is a difficulty with the $\log$ function at $-1$, and for $x < 0$ we get the formula $$\arctan(x) = \frac{1}{2i} \log(\frac{x-i}{x+i}) - \frac{\pi}{2}$$ by a similar argument.

That the logarithm and inverse trigonometric functions are related shouldn't be surprising, though. Remember Euler's formula: $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$ that relates the exponential to the trigonometric functions.

Comment: Surely the logarithmic term will be multivalued? Or this covered by the fact the inverse tangent is also multivalued? (Infact, now I think about it, it is indeed)

Comment: @AndrewD You're right, both are multivalued, but unfortunately not in quite the same way

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are fine. However, to my taste, there  is a more conceptual explanation involving covering space theory.

In summary, the above relationship between inverse tangent and complex logarithm holds since *the tangent function and exponential function are "essentially the same" universal topological covering map.* In even more informal terms, the exponential map and the tangent are (up to isomorphism) both a solution to the same optimization problem (if one views a universal cover, or more generally a universal object, as a solution to an optimization problem, as done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3239188/how-are-universal-properties-solutions-to-optimization-problems)).

Let me explain. Firstly, both the exponential function $$\operatorname{exp}\colon \mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$$
and the tangent function
$$\operatorname{tan}\colon \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{\pm i\}$$
are universal covers. Here, $\mathbb{P}^1$ denotes the Riemann sphere.

Now, take a homeomorphism $f\colon \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{\pm i\}$. As an example, consider the following (restricted) Möbius transformation
$$f(z):=-i\cdot\frac{z-1}{z+1}.$$
This map is induced from the unique automorphism
$\hat{f}$ of the Riemann sphere with $\hat{f}(0)=i, \hat{f}(\infty)=-i$ and $\hat{f}(1)=0.$ Its inverse is given by
$$f^{-1}(z)=\frac{i-z}{i+z}.$$
Next, consider the following diagram of covering maps
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} \mathbb{C} @.\mathbb{C}\\ @V\operatorname{exp} VV @VV\operatorname{tan}V\\ \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}@>>f> \mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{\pm i\} \end{CD}$$

Since $\operatorname{exp}\colon \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is a universal cover and $f$ is a biholomorphism (in particular a homeomorphism), the composition $f\circ \operatorname{exp}\colon \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{\pm  i\}$ is a universal cover.
Furthermore, we have $f(\operatorname{exp}(0))=0=\operatorname{tan}(0)$.

In other words, the covering maps $f\circ\operatorname{exp}\colon (\mathbb{C},0)\rightarrow (\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{\pm i\},0)$ and $\operatorname{tan}\colon (\mathbb{C},0)\rightarrow (\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{\pm i\},0)$ are both initial objects in the category of (pointed) coverings of the pointed topological space $(\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{\pm i\},0)$. The objects of this category are covering maps $p\colon(X,x)\rightarrow (\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{\pm i\},0)$ with $p(x)=0$. Here, $(X,x)$ is any topological space $X$ with base point $x$. The morphisms are fiber-preserving continuous maps between coverings of $(\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{\pm i\},0)$ that preserve the base point.

Now, initial objects are unique up to unique isomorphism. Said differently, there exists a unique homeomorphism $g\colon \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $g(0)=0$ such that the following diagram commutes
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} \mathbb{C} @>g>>\mathbb{C}\\ @V\operatorname{exp} VV @VV\operatorname{tan}V\\ \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}@>>f> \mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{\pm i\} \end{CD}$$
This mapping reads as $g(z)=\frac{1}{2i}z$. It should not come as a suprise that $g$ has to be an automorphism of the complex plane (and hence of the form $g(z)=az$ with $a\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$): A lift of a holomorphic mapping between Riemann surfaces along a unbranched holomorphic covering map is necessarily holomorphic (see Theorem 4.9 in Forster's *Lectures on Riemann surfaces*).

Anyways, by reversing arrows (and choosing branches of complex logarithm and tangent) we obtain the formula given in Michael Hardy's answer

$$\operatorname{arctan}(z)=(g\circ \operatorname{log}\circ f^{-1})(z)=\frac{1}{2i}\operatorname{log}\big(\frac{i-z}{i+z}\big).$$