# Definite integral - Different answers while using different approaches to solve

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I wanted to ask whether it is possible to get 2 different answers for the same definite integral, using two different approaches to solve it.

My friend and I have received an exercise in which we were requested to evaluate the result of a definite integral.

I've used the universal trigonometric substitution, and got an answer which was a combination of ln(x) functions, while he has used regular substitution, and has received an answer that was composed out of arctan(x) functions.

How is this possible?
Both of us, have checked our way multiple times, and are sure of our solutions.

The integral I was referring to:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^{2}(x) + 4\cdot \cos(x) + 5} dx$$

Thanks!

Comment: What is the integral? Maybe a wrong use of formula is causing this problem.

Comment: No, clearly not, one of the approaches (maybe both) must contain some mistakes.

Comment: Sometimes there are different expressions for the same value.

Comment: What are the two expressions?

Comment: You should get $\arctan(3)-\arctan(2)$.

Comment: That is what you get using regular substitution. Any chance you could try solving it using universal trigonometric substitution? You should get a different result

Comment: @ChenMordechay Why not _answer the question_ that's been asked? What _is_ the other result? It could be it's actually the same but just looks different - can't tell if you refuse to tell us what it is...

Comment: What exactly is "regular substitution"? Some terms do not have worldwide usage, and this seems to be one of them. Anyway, the substitution $x = 2 \arctan t$ leads to $\int _0 ^1 \frac {2t} {t^4 + 4t^2 + 5} \ \Bbb d t = \int _0 ^1 \frac {(t^2 + 2)'} {(t^2 + 2)^2 + 1} \ \Bbb d t = \arctan (t^2 + 2) \Big| _0 ^1 = \arctan 3 - \arctan 2$. Another, much faster substitution is $\cos x = t$.

Comment: Just use a calculator and compare the values of the two solutions. Probably you found a different expression for the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Some functions are related by deep connections. Consider the innocent-looking function $\operatorname{arctanh}$ ("hyperbolic arctangent").

If $x = \operatorname{arctanh} t$, then $\tanh x = t$, which means $\frac {\Bbb e^x - \Bbb e^{-x}} {\Bbb e^x + \Bbb e^{-x}} = t$. With the notation $u = \Bbb e^t$, the above becomes $u - \frac 1 u - tu - t \frac 1 u = 0$, which rearranges to $u^2(1-t) = 1+t$, so $u = \frac {1+t} {1-t}$ (I chose the positive root because $u = \Bbb e ^x >0$). Taking the logarithm, you get $x = \ln \frac {1+t} {1-t}$, which shows that $\operatorname{arctanh} t = \ln \frac {1+t} {1-t}$ - which I bet that you were not expecting.

I believe that something similar happens in your case (sometimes one can get results like these by taking a real formula, moving it to the complex plane, doing some manipulations on it, and finally miraculously taking it back to the reals). It is known that [$\arctan$ can be expressed in terms of $\ln$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414248/why-does-arctanx-frac12i-log-left-fracx-ixi-rightk), like $\operatorname{arctanh}$ above, but the price to pay is the usage of $\sqrt {-1}$.