# What is the universal covering surface of a 2-sphere with two holes at the poles?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

For a graph $G(V, E)$ embedded in the 2-sphere $S_2$, $V=\{s, t, v_1, v_2\}$, $s$ and $t$ are located at the two poles of the $S_2$. There exists two paths $sv_1t$, $sv_2t$ in $G$. Now we have a surface $U$ obtained in the following way:

1. Cut out holes in $S_2$ at $s$ and $t$. This transforms the sphere into a cylinder where the boundaries or holes at the ends are identified with $s$ and $t$.
2. Make a cut from one end of the cylinder to the other to obtain a rectangle.
3. Taking an infinite number of copies of this rectangle and glueing them together to form an infinitely long strip (surface $U$) whose two boundaries are again identified with the nodes $s$ and $t$.

Is U the universal covering surface of $S_2\backslash\{s, t\}$? If so, does U look like the one drawn below?

[image]

Comment: Sphere minus a point is homeorphic to 2-plane and removing another point is same as removing on point from 2-plane.

Comment: You space is homeomorphic to $S^1\times \mathbb R$, whose universal cover is $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ where the first map is the universal cover $\mathbb R\to S^1$ and the second map is the identity.

Answer (score 0):

As Pedro mentions in the comments, the complex plane with euclidean topology is the universal covering space of $S^2\setminus\{v_1,v_2\}$. For an explicit covering map consider the exponential map
$$\operatorname{exp}\colon \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\cong \overline{\mathbb{C}}\setminus\{0,\infty\}\cong S^2\setminus\{v_1,v_2\}.$$
Here, we identify $S^2$ with the one-point compactification $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ of $\mathbb{C}$ via stereographic projection. Similarly, we identify $v_1\in S^2$ with $0\in\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ and $v_2\in S^2$ with $\infty\in\overline{\mathbb{C}}.$ If you identify $v_1$ and $v_2$ with different points of $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$, you can construct a covering map $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow S^2\setminus\{v_1,v_2\}$ by composing the exponential function with a suitable Möbius transformation (i.e., an automorphism of the Riemann sphere). For an example, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414248/why-does-arctanx-frac12i-log-left-fracx-ixi-rightk/4653928#4653928), for instance.

---

Since I am not sure what you mean by "taking an infinite number of copies of this rectangle and glueing them together" (i.e. how do you glue?), I cannot answer whether your space $U$ is the universal covering space of $S^2\setminus\{v_1,v_2\}$.